# link lib which build by different c++ standard

Tags: c++, linker

Does it OK to compile an application by c++11 and link against a lib which compiled by C++98?
vice versa? (Same compiler)
I think it should be OK, because the name mangle, memory align should be same

Comment: I think this is completely implementation-defined.

Comment: I once asked [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10717106/596781).

Comment: What makes you think they should be the same? Lots of types have different member functions and extended functionality, different requirements etc. I would not expect it to work at all.