# How to keep from linking different "versions" of nested libraries?

Tags: c++, dependencies, static-libraries

Suppose I have the following two libraries which implement the type (i.e., struct) Lib.

**Library A**

```
//library.hpp
struct Lib
{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
};
```

**Library B**

```
//library.hpp
struct Lib
{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned char d;
    unsigned char e;
};
```

I then create another library which must "use" one of these libraries as such.  In this example, it is going to use library B.

```
#include <lib.hpp>

//common.cpp
void printLib(std::ostream& os, const Lib& l)
{
    os << std::hex << "l.a = " << l.a << std::endl;
    os << std::hex << "l.b = " << static_cast<unsigned int>(l.b) << std::endl;
    os << std::hex << "l.c = " << static_cast<unsigned int>(l.c) << std::endl;
    os << std::hex << "l.d = " << static_cast<unsigned int>(l.d) << std::endl;
    os << std::hex << "l.e = " << static_cast<unsigned int>(l.e) << std::endl;
}
```

However, the application links against Library A and calls `printLib` as such:

```
#include <library.hpp>
#include <common.hpp>

int main()
{
    Lib l;
    
    l.a = 0xAABBCCDD;
    l.b = 0x11223344;
    
    printLib(std::cout, l);
        
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles just fine except that the result will be very unexpected since the application and "common" library have built against a different version of the library.

My intent is to write the common library such that it works with any class `Lib` that meets some "named requirements." In other words I want to be able to switch the implementation by switching which library is linked rather than changing the code.  From my understanding, this is how the standard library specification works.  The implementations of the standard library types might be wildly different (and thus the object layout similar to what I've shown), but all compliant standard library versions meet some "named requirements" and thus you can build/link your code against any of them.

As an embedded programmer, this comes up quite often for me.  For example, suppose I want to write code to use `std::mutex`.  Well, my platform may not have a standard implementation of `std::mutex` so I write my own to, for example, work with FreeRTOS.  My application could should be allowed to build/link against both without issue.  However, all parts of the system MUST use the same implementation or I'm in for some strange problems.

Here's a question related to mine: [Are there hidden dangers to link libraries compiled with different C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67500470/are-there-hidden-dangers-to-link-libraries-compiled-with-different-c-standard)

How do you prevent something link this from occurring?  Is this a case of needing some better form of dependency management?

Comment: both libraries should use namespaces rather than defining stuff in the global namespace. If you write your own mutex you can call it `my::mutex`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai But what do I do if my intent is to write the common library such that it works with any class Lib (or mutex) that meets the "named requirements?"  In other words I want to be able to switch the implementation by switching which library is linked rather than changing the code.

Comment: Re your added paragraph: Some standard lib implementations take pains to preserve binary compatibility (if you have all the right magic preprocessor defines and compiler flags) with older versions of themself (i.e. a program or lib compiled for libstdc++-v4 could likely be linked to libstdc++-v7 with the right incantation), but there is zero chance you will ever be able to compile against one standard lib implementation and link against a different one (i.e. compile against libstdc++ and link to libc++).

Comment: @MilesBudnek Based upon this feedback, perhaps I should change direction slightly.  How would this be handled in the "field" then (for any library not necessarily just the standard library)?  Would I need to provide multiple compiled libraries of "common", one for library A and one for library B?  Then the application is responsible for linking against the correct one?

Comment: That depends on your exact goal really.  If your library is open source (or you users are internal) then you can just distribute it as source and let the user compile it against the library they're using.  If it's not, then either multiple builds of the "common" library or a single build that provides interfaces for either backing library (with appropriate preprocessor defines and careful planning to make sure only the object files for the appropriate library get linked to).