# Is mixing C++11 and C++20 allowed with GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc

I declare a struct in a header file. I use this struct in two compilation units. One is compiled with [-std=c++11](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-std-1) and the other with -std=c++20. The sizeof my struct is different in the two compilation units.

Is it allowed to mix any -std=c++20 and -std=c++11 code or am I using GCC the wrong way?

These answers do not tell if it's expected to work.

- I'm not using two different version of « the same » compiler ([Can you mix c++ compiled with different versions of the same compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895081/can-you-mix-c-compiled-with-different-versions-of-the-same-compiler)).
- I'm not mixing two incompatible versions of the standard in my code, as far as I know ([Mixing different C++ standards with GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056849/mixing-different-c-standards-with-gcc)).
- I'm not using libraries, including standard libraries (except for displaying the results, but that's not where the problem lies) ([Is it safe to link C++17, C++14, and C++11 objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746878/is-it-safe-to-link-c17-c14-and-c11-objects)).

I'm using GCC ([Debian 10.2.1-6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_10_(Buster)) (Buster)) 10.2.1 20210110 on [Debian 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_11_(Bullseye)) (Bullseye). I wonder if this version of GCC has a bug.

Code demonstrating the problem:

#### File *1.h*

```
#ifndef DEF1
#define DEF1

#include "c.h"

void f1(C* c);
C* g1();
#endif
```

#### File *2.h*

```
#ifndef DEF2
#define DEF2

#include "c.h"

void f2 (C* c);
C* g2();
#endif
```

#### File *1.cpp*

```
#include "c.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void f1 (C* c)
{
  printf("sizeof(C)=%ld\n", sizeof(C));
  printf("i2=%d\n", c->i2);
  printf("&i2-&i1=%ld\n", ((char*)&c->i2) - ((char*)&c->i1));
}

C* g1()
{
  C* c = new C;
  c->i2 = 1;
  return c;
}
```

#### File *2.cpp*

```
#include "c.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void f2 (C* c)
{
  printf("sizeof(C)=%ld\n", sizeof(C));
  printf("i2=%d\n", c->i2);
  printf("&i2-&i1=%ld\n", ((char*)&c->i2) - ((char*)&c->i1));
}

C* g2()
{
  C* c = new C;
  c->i2 = 2;
  return c;
}
```

#### File *c.h*

```
#ifndef CDEF
#define CDEF

#include <stdint.h>

struct A
{
    double d1{0.0};
    double d2{0.0};
    double d3{0.0};
    double d4{0.0};
    double d5{0.0};
    double d6{0.0};
    double d7{0.0};
    int32_t i1{};
};

#ifdef DER
struct C : public A
{
    int32_t i2{};
};
#else
struct C
{
    double d1{0.0};
    double d2{0.0};
    double d3{0.0};
    double d4{0.0};
    double d5{0.0};
    double d6{0.0};
    double d7{0.0};
    int32_t i1{};
    int32_t i2{};
};
#endif
#endif
```

#### File *main.cpp*

```
#include "c.h"
#include "1.h"
#include "2.h"

int main()
{
  f1(g2());
  f2(g1());
}
```

#### File *bar.sh*

```
g++ -std=c++20 -DDER -c 2.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -DDER -c 1.cpp
g++ -std=c++20 -DDER -c main.cpp
g++ -std=c++20 2.o 1.o main.o -o prog
./prog
```

#### Executing *./bar.sh*

```
sizeof(C)=64
i2=0
&i2-&i1=4
sizeof(C)=72
i2=0
&i2-&i1=8
```

Comment: *"Is mixing c++11 and c++20 allowed with gcc..."* **Don't just don't.** I wouldn't recommend doing this. [Can you mix c++ compiled with different versions of the same compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895081/can-you-mix-c-compiled-with-different-versions-of-the-same-compiler)

Comment: [Can i safely mix libraries compiled with -std=c++11 and -std=c++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296917/can-i-safely-mix-libraries-compiled-with-std-c11-and-std-c14)

Comment: What is not explicitely disallowed may be considered allowed, but it doesn't mean it's a good idea. Mixing different versions may cause compatibility issues or worse, unexpected bugs. I would not recommend doing such a thing at all. You need to port the old code to the new version you're targeting.

Comment: @user12002570 I am using the same compiler (so not two different versions) and the answers to the second question and those referenced in them warn about the libraries although my example does not use any library. I understand it's not a good idea : it does not work in my example. I wonder if it's expected to work or expected that it may not work. I'm sorry if my question is unclear.

Comment: In GCC 13 the struct has the same size in C++11 and C++20 modes, so maybe this is a bug that was fixed.

Comment: This seems to be a gcc bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103681

Comment: Thanks @kjpus, you've found it ! and I see no complaint in the link you provide from gcc maintainers that this use of the compiler is wrong (but it may still be ;).

Comment: You certainly can mix-and-match any versions of C++ you want in a single application.  As long as those pieces interop with each other through a C ABI firewall.

Comment: @Eljay 99% of the time you don't need any firewall. Things just work. And when they don:t work, the firewall doesn't save you, so again you don't need it.

Comment: GCC docs explicitly state that mixing C++ versions in the same executable is normal and supported (at least for C++11 and newer), and when it doesn't work, this is a GCC bug. See for example these GCC10 release notes https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html

Comment: Oh and MSVC has a stable C++ ABI since 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is allowed, *modulo bugs in GCC*.

### The compiler

GCC follows the [Itanium ABI](https://github.com/itanium-cxx-abi/cxx-abi), which is actually platform-independent, despite the name. Here is the Itanium ABI mission statement:

> we want users to be able to build relocatable objects with different compilers and link them together, and if possible even to ship common DSOs.

Note there are no separate ABI specifications for separate versions of the C++ standard. There is one specification that works for them all.

### The library

Here is the mission statement of libstdc++ as far as versioning is concerned

> Extending existing, stable ABIs. Versioning gives subsequent releases of library binaries the ability to add new symbols and add functionality, all the while retaining compatibility with the previous releases in the series. Thus, program binaries linked with the initial release of a library binary will still run correctly if the library binary is replaced by carefully-managed subsequent library binaries. This is called forward compatibility.

The library supports not one, but two different ABIs. There was a change in the C++11 standard that necessitated an ABI split. However, as the documentation points out, [the choice of ABI to use is independent of the `-std` option used to compile your code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html). This is ancient history however. You are going to use the new C++11-compatible ABI, which is the default, about 100% of the time, unless you need to maintain an old piece of software built with pre-C++11-compatible ABI.

### The real life

The open source ecosystem has zillions of C++ libraries that are used in all kind of products. No one coordinates `-std` option between maintainers of different libraries. Everybody upstream uses what they want/need, and downstream the libraries are built with whatever options are there, and linked together with no problem. It all just works.

I personally run Gentoo, which is a rolling release distro. I fetch whatever stable release of a software component is available directly from that library's GitHub or whatever it is stored, and compile with whatever compiler version I currently have. I can recompile any library using any compiler version at any time. The system still works just fine. Without this kind of cross-standard, cross-version compatibility, a rolling release would never ever have a chance to work.

### Conclusion

Is it 100% safe? You decide. There are compiler bugs in this area (you have found one) and sometimes people get biten by them. Then again, there are compiler bugs in all areas, but people still use compilers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be reproduced with this small code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { 
    double d{0.0};
    int i1{1};
};

struct C : public A { 
    int i2{2};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    C c;
    std::cout << "sizeof(C) = " << sizeof(C) << std::endl;
              << "&i2 - &i1 = " << (((char*) &c.i2) - ((char*) &c.i1))
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `G++` in C++11 mode or when compiled with `clang` (any mode), the result is:

```
sizeof(C) = 16
&i2 - &i1 = 4
```

When compiled with `G++` in C++14 (or later) mode, the result is:

```
sizeof(C) = 24
&i2 - &i1 = 8
```

Apparently, `G++` since C++14 refuses to overlay fields of `struct C` into `struct A`. Note that `sizeof(A)` is 16 with all compilers, which is required, so that arrays of objects of type `A` are well-aligned. So there is an implicit 4-byte padidng after `i1`. `clang` (all versions) and `G++` (until C++11) recycle that padding, when another `int` is added through inheritance, `G++` (later versions) does not.

This is clearly a binary compatibility breaking change between C++11 and C++14 mode in `G++`, that can manifest itself in many places of custom code, so linking mixed-compiled code is very dangerous, if the oldest version used is C++11.

Actually, the `G++` team seems to have acknowledged this as a bug and fixed it for `G++12` and later versions, but has not backported it to older versions of the compiler, so this issue is still present in `G++11`, which is for example the default compiler in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Here a link to the GCC bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103681 Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/5293624/kjpus for reporting this link.

As can be easily verified on Godbolt, the bug is present in `G++` version 11.4, but fixed from version 12.1 on: https://godbolt.org/z/chnss5bs3