# Can I link objects compiled from C++ by GCC 5.4.x and 6.x?

Tags: c++, linker, compatibility, abi, gcc6

For some reason, I have some object files compiled with GCC 5.4.x and some object files compiled with GCC 6.x . The source code is C++14 and I'm on a x86_64 machine running GNU/Linux 4.4.x.

Is it ever, at all, possible to link my objects together? If so, what are the restrictions/conditions for it to be possible, or what procedure do I need to follow to make it possible?

Comment: You don't need to do anything, it works and is a supported use case.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10717106

Comment: You need to link them together. If you don't get any unresolved symbols, then it works. I believe these two particular versions are compatible. You need to use the standard library from the 6.x version.

Comment: @n.m.: Do you mean I need to compile the 5.4.x C++ sources with the 6.x standard library headers, or just use the 6.x standard library for linking?

Comment: The latter. There's nothing to compile, you are only linking.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Really? No restrictions at all? Different flags? It will "just work?? ... If so, please make it an answer :-)

Comment: If you use flags that change ABI (such as `-fshort-enums`) then it won't work, but that's true even if you compile all objects with the same compiler version and use ABI-changing flags for some objects and not others. G++ 6 is backwards compatible with GCC 5. At run-time you need to use the `libstdc++.so` from the newest compiler version used for any of the objects in the link.